# Understanding Feynman's argument that probability of microstate depends on energy only

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In *Statistical Mechanics: A Set Of Lectures*, Feynman argues that if we have a system in contact with a heat bath, then the probability that the system occupies a given state is a function of the state's energy only. In section 1.1 (I didn't get very far!), he writes:

> Consider two different states of the system that have the same energy, $E_r = E_s$. The probabilities of the system being in states $r$ and $s$ are then equal. For if the system is in state $r$, any extremely small perturbation will cause the system to go into a different state of essentially the same energy, such as $s$. The same is true if the system is in state $s$. Since the system remains in contact with the heat bath for a long time, one would expect states of equal energy to be equally likely.

I have two questions about this argument.

**1.    Why is it that small perturbations cause the system to move between states of similar energy?**

My guess is that he's thinking about (first-order) time-dependent perturbation theory, in which perturbations of frequency $\Omega$ give transitions with energy difference centered around $\hbar\Omega$. Perhaps the perturbation frequency is small in some sense? (Small compared to what?)

This isn't what I would expect though. If the system is in contact with a solid heat bath, wouldn't thermal vibrations in the bath cause transitions between different energies?

**2.    Why does the fact that the system can easily transition between two states of similar energy imply that they are equally likely (in other words, that the system spends about as much time in each state)?**

If the system is initially in state $m$, the amplitude to be in $n$ as time goes on is

$$ c_n(t) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t\left<n|\delta H(t')|m\right> e^{i(E_n-E_m)t'/\hbar} dt'. $$

So, if we have two states $r$ and $s$ with equal energy, but one of them has larger matrix elements $\left<\text{rest}|\delta H|r\text{ or }s\right>$ with the rest of the energy eigenstates, then couldn't that asymmetry lead to $r$ and $s$ having a different probability?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically right to say that the quick argument offered by Feynman is not on its own enough to be convincing, because of the sort of issue you point out. A more careful treatment would have to focus on this issue for longer and discuss the temporal evolution of the system, as you suggest. Maybe Feynman will do that later in the book. In any case it is a standard part of any thorough treatment of statistical mechanics, though strangely it seems to be not much remarked in lecture notes and introductory courses.

When one approaches statistical mechanics from classical physics this is related to Liouville's theorem. In the arguments from quantum physics one has to argue that the system takes a fixed time on average to move from one state to an orthogonal state of the same energy.

Comment: Thanks Prof Steane! Is there a particular book that you'd recommend for a thorough treatment which discusses these quantum mechanical arguments?

Comment: @TEF sorry I don't have to hand the books I have used in the past and can't remember the authors now, but if I find them then I'll add another comment.